# All factors when live streaming in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sdk, live-streaming

I am attempting to make my app, this is an app that will integrate live streaming that could be accessed by anyone that is signed up. I have been searching and the information is *very vague*.

**What factors do I have to take into consideration to make an IOS app with live streaming?**
I would have no clue how to implement any of this and I haven't seen much documentation about how to implement this. **What third party software would I have to use, would I need to create something in a different programming language?**

This app is going to be only for IOS for now.

*Thanks,*

Comment: Hello, let me know if you found a solution and what did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, how many users? How much do you want to spend? How critical is performance/quality/downtime, etc.? Is this a business app?
Due to having multiple users connect to one stream, I would suggest that the streamer streams it to a server, whereby the server deals with the bandwidth requirements to clients, allowing for it to more easily scale. If it is a one-on-one or up to maybe one on three, you could still think of p2p for a social stream (e.g. streaming to family) but not e.g. a business conference (unless you want them to have e2e encryption, avoiding server, etc. which is usually complete overkill, though do implement encryption if possible, quite easy using libraries).
Now if you're asking coding wise, look for some tutorials, e.g. https://www.raywenderlich.com/5191-video-streaming-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started is quite nice, it's quite straight forward and will probably do what you want for the client accessing it. Use the AVFoundation Playback https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/ it has links to HTTP live streaming and how to implement it as well.

Comment: It is a fitness app so quality is a lot of it, as of now I'm just looking at free trials and just start executing on my idea. I plan to have many users under one video at a time. Think of it like a twitch just in the fitness industry.

Comment: You'll need a web server to host the stream, look at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/deploying_a_basic_http_live_stream
The most important thing here is going to be bandwidth and latency, so pick a server that is hosted in the region that your target audience is and pick a server with a bit of bandwidth. A way around would be looking at streaming via integrating e.g. YouTube. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618851/how-to-embed-youtube-or-facebook-live-streaming-in-my-ios-app
which would deal with encoding into variable bitrates.

Comment: I would actually recommend the YouTube approach over self hosting, you can look at making it unlisted if you don't want it searchable, just make it so the app stores the url for clients. Would also make it easy to then embed into websites or port to android, etc. as you are just embedding the video.

Comment: problem might be adds, look at Vimeo but live streaming is only with pro at $75 a month, might be cheaper then to do self hosting. Again, the most important is budget. It might (and usually is better) to upload edited content as you can then project better quality.